# Office.initialize is not called randomly in dialog

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am using `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync` to open a dialog. After authentication and a couple of redirects, the dialog eventually redirects to a simple page that is responsible for calling back the parent.

Here is the code of page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Loading...</title>

    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(1);
        Office.initialize = function () {
            document.write(2);
            Office.context.ui.messageParent('Hello World!');
            document.write(3);
        };
        document.write(5);

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Loading...
</body>
</html>
```

Sometimes, `Office.initialize` is called and all 5 `document.write` statements are printed however, sometimes, randomly only 1 & 5 are printed. Which means that `Office.initialize` was not called.

Is it a bug in office.js or am I doing something wrong?

- OS: MacOS High Sierra (10.13.4)
- Outlook version: 16.11 (180311)

**Update:** I tried the same code on Office Online. It works fine on Firefox & Chrome. However, on Safari, the behavior is the same as Outlook Desktop. As the Outlook Desktop on MacOS uses Safari, can this be something related to Office.js compatibility with Safari?

**Update2:** I have used VanillaJS instead and it works flawlessly on:

- Outlook Desktop (MacOS)
- Outlook Web on Firefox
- Outlook Web on Chrome
- Outlook Web on Safari

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Loading...</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            window.opener.postMessage("Hello World!"), window.location.origin);
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Loading...
</body>
</html>
```

In parent window, I use:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event){
    if(event.origin !== window.origin) return;
    console.log(event.data);
}, false);
```

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, could you wrap the line that makes the assignment to Office.initialize in an if ... then structure that checks to see if the Office object is defined?

Comment: @RickKirkham I tried that and `Office` is always defined.

Comment: Do you have a Windows machine available? It might be informative to see if this happens on Windows. Also, you could try testing it on Office Online. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing

Comment: I do not have Outlook on windows machine. I tried it on Office Online. It behaves the same in Safari. However, it works fine on Chrome & Firefox. So probably it is something related to Office lib's compatibility with Safari?

Comment: This does look like a bug with Office.js and Safari. I suggest that you raise this as an issue on this repo: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js. Include a link to this StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 2):

Though it doesn't seem to be the case in your simple repro, there are -- in general -- two issues with today's `Office.initialize`:

1. The place where you call it makes a difference.  Call it too late (e.g., 3 seconds later in a `setTimeout`, to use a contrived examples), and it won't fire.
2. You can only have a single `Office.initialize` declared (you can't have multiple ones, because you're directly setting the object).

The good news is that this is going to change very soon!  We are about to release an API to replace (or rather, append, but with the intention of having one supercede the other) `Office.initialize` with something that addresses both issues.  An "Office.onReady" API, that can be used as follows:

`Office.onReady(function() {
    console.log("Office is now ready 1!");
});
Office.onReady(function() {
    console.log("Office is now ready 2!");
});
// And both should fire, after the host is ready`

or as a Promise:

`Office.onReady()
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Office is now ready 1!");
    });
Office.onReady()
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Office is now ready 2!");
    });`

or even with TypeScript's async/await:

`(async () => {
    await Office.onReady();
    console.log("Office is now ready!");
})();`

And with Office.onReady, it shouldn't matter where you call it.  If you call it before the host is ready, we will wait to fire it until the host *is* ready.  Or if you call it some time later, we'll just immediately fire -- just like jQuery's `$(document).ready`.

If you'd like to try it, could you please reference the build from https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/office-js@1.1.7-release-next.0/dist/office.js, and see whether this API works for you.  (Unpkg is a virtual CDN service, not affiliated with Microsoft -- but it does provide an easy way to test things, and is often used elsewhere in the web community).  If it works, the good news is that the API should be on the CDN soon (in a matter of weeks).  If it doesn't, then we have to dig deeper.

Would love to get your usage and input.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I tried `Office.onReady()` with 1.1.7 build but it has the same random behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Office.initialize is an event when the add-in is ready to interact with the application and hosted document. Therefore, the sequence in your code snippet should be like: 1, 5, 2, 3. If the later two numbers are missing randomly, it could be a bug in office.js. How about the behavior in browsers, like IE/Edge? Are the numbers missing randomly as well?